# How can I check my print statements in the test?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, stdout

I am trying to write test function for my print function. But there I got problem. Can you help me if I'm doing it in a right way? and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The name is `readouterr`, not `readoutter`.

Comment: I have change it, but you can help me to understand what I'm doing here wrong? This is my first time when I'm using capture. @chepner

Comment: Your expected output is incorrect - you expect a space that isn't printed. Also, when asking a question, please paste the errors _as text_, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` is just the argument you'll pass to `func`.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('name, expected_out',
                     [('bob', '\n bob\n You have finished your test.\n')])

def test_func(capsys, name, expected_out):
   func(name)
   out, _ = capsys.readouterr()
   assert out == expected_out
```

Comment: I changed it, but it didn't work again. Anyway thanks a lot. @chepner